# Bounded solution ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the system

$$x'(t) = y(t)$$
$$y'(t) = -y(t)^3 - p(x(t))$$

with initial condition $(x(0),y(0)) = (x_0,y_0)$ and $p(x(t))$ is a polynomial of odd degree with positive leading coefficient. I have to show that the solution $(x(t),y(t))$ is bounded for all $t \geq 0$. I am not sure how to start. I am guessing I need to look for a monotone quantity. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to look at the linearised system around a point $t_0>0$? You should get something like $\begin{pmatrix}x'(t)\\y'(t)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\p'(x(t_0))&-3y(t_0))^2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x(t)\\y(t)\end{pmatrix}$. Assuming that $x(t)\to\pm\infty$ as $t\to+\infty$ would yield a negative determinant for the matrix (here you use that the dominating coefficient in $P'(x(t_0))$ contains $x(t_0)^{2n}$ with $\mathrm{deg}(p)=2n+1$). This would give two complex eigenvalues with negative real part $-3y(t_0))^2/2$ hence decaying solutions, a contradiction. So $x$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$p(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}a_kt^k\qquad\qquad a_0,\ldots, a_{2n+1}\in\mathbb{R}.$$
Assume that $x$ is not bounded as $t\to+\infty$. The linearized system around $t_0>0$ reads
$$\begin{pmatrix}x_0'(t)\\y_0'(t)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-p'(x(t_0))&-3y(t_0))^2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_0(t)\\y_0(t)\end{pmatrix}.$$
The matrix has two eigenvalues $\lambda\pm$ which satisfy
$$\lambda_-+\lambda_+=-3y(t_0)^2,\qquad\lambda_-\lambda_+=p'(x(t_0)).$$
We find:
$$\lambda_\pm=-\frac{3y(t_0)^2}{2}\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{9y(t_0))^4-4p'(x(t_0))}.$$
By assumption, the leading term $(2n+1)a_{2n+1}(x(t_0))^{2n}$ of $p'(x(t_0))$ is positive, so $\lambda_\pm$ have negative real part. It follows that the solutions $(x_0,y_0)$ of the linearized system are decaying in time. This implies that the solutions $(x,y)$ are also bounded (as they must be close to $(x_0,y_0)$ when $t$ is close to $t_0$ for any $t_0>0$). This contradicts the assumption on $x$.

Hence $x(t)$ is bounded for $t\in[0,+\infty)$. Now the equation $x'(t)=y(t)$ implies that $y$ is bounded too.

Answer (score 0):

Take some integral $P$ of $p$. The leading term then has even degree, so all sets $\{x:P(x)<c\}$ are bounded. Assume that the integration constant is chosen so that $P$ only takes non-negative values.

Then $L(x,y)=\frac12y^2+P(x)$ is a Lyapunov function of the system,
$$
\frac{d}{dt}L(x(t),y(t))=-y(t)^4
$$
means that if $c=L(x(0),y(0))$, then $L(x(t),y(t))\le c$ for all $t\ge 0$. The level sets of $L$ are likewise bounded, as also $|y|\le \sqrt{2c}$. Moreover, the solution can only become stationary in $y=0$ if also $0=p(x)=P'(x)$, that is, in one of the equilibrium points of the system. Else the solution descends towards one of the minimum points of $P$.